# Sending email to Amazon SES in PHP freezes when triggered by request

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Unable to send an email on demand using AWS SesClient

I am trying to send an email for a password recovery on demand. That is I receive an http request in my API and I call sendBulkTemplatedEmail() through a function called `send_email()`.

Here is the thing:

- If I execute the php file containing the previous code from the server command line using `php finename.php`, the email is sent successfully.
- However, when the function is triggered by a request, `sendBulkTemplatedEmailfunction` simply freezes.

```
    send_email($destination_email, $type){
        /.../   
        try {
            $SesClient->sendBulkTemplatedEmail($data_to_attach);
            $messageId = 1;
            echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");
            return true;
        } catch (AwsException $e) {
            /..../
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that a **different user** is being used in each case.

When you run `php` from the command-line, it is running as your logged-in user (`ec2-user`?). However, when it is triggered via a request, it is running as a different user (`apache`?), and that user does not have credentials in their `~/.aws/credentials` file.

This can be fixed by copying the credentials to the other user's `~/.aws` directory.

Comment: Definitely a credentials issue. It is necessary to generate a Ses credential and give access to the specific Ses function o be used (from the AWS console) so that it can be reached from an API call. Then, adding those when a SesClient object is created in your code will make the trick!